# Persist Jasper reports result set output to structured database table in an automated way?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ireport, jasperserver

I am developing a Jasper report (jrxml file) using iReport (5.0.1), with an SQL Server 2008 stored procedure to generate a result set for the report.
In the stored procedure I am attempting to save the result set to a permanent table on the SQL Server (e.g. CREATE TABLE, or SELECT INTO).  When I run the jrxml file in iReport, the stored procedure code works as expected and the result set is saved.  However, when I deploy the jrxml to Jasperserver 5.5.0 and run it there, the report is generated, but the result set data are not persisted to the SQL Server (it appears that when run on the Jasperserver, all tables generated are treated as temporary tables and/or cleaned up).  Is there a configuration parameter of the Jasperserver that allows/disallows saving of the result set data to the database?  Is there a way to persist Jasper report data in a structured format in an automated way?

Comment: Are you trying to cache a rather expensive Stored Procedure request? Is the CREATE TABLE/SELECT INTO commands within the Stored Proc? Or within the Report?